# Slick 1.0.1 batch insert how to ignore error and return success entries

Tags: scala, slick

I am using slick's `insertAll` and found it only return inserted rows count or None or throws Exception if any failure

> How to ignore errors and find which entries are inserted, which are not.(I really don't want to modify `BasicInvokerComponent` )

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting or why not use `withTransaction` to prevent any insertion in case of error.

Comment: @cvogt I just want to ignore the error entries, (for example duplicated key)

Comment: Also posted on mailing list. Please cross-link yourself in the future: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/Ome0CaaAE4c/lh9YD-x_NDwJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insertAll` uses a transaction internally. Accordingly, if an exception is thrown, no change is committed to the database. Or in other words, you cannot ignore only the ones failing. If you expect some to fail, filter them out before inserting.

For returning ids from an insertion you can use the `returning` syntax. See http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#inserting

Comment: So, it is not possible to ignore error, the only way is to avoid the error